# Adding CSS styles to a block

Tags: 8, theming

**UPDATED** *Added other files just in case the error is somewhere else*

I just created a custom module for Drupal 8 that defines a block. I want to add some CSS styles to the content of the block.

My last attempt to achieve this was adding a libraries.yml file to the module linking the block_header.css file. In the render array, I added #prefix and #suffix with the CSS classes (`<div class='foo'>`).

The code doesn't give me any error, but it's not applying the font weight I would expect.

Could you point me to the right direction?

These are the files.

#### block_header.info.yml

```
name: Block Header creator
type: module
description: 'Create block with a main header and a text on mouseover'
core: 8.x
package: Fussion Corp - Custom Modules
configure: block_header.settings
```

#### block_header.routing.yml

```
block.content:
  path: '/block'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\block_header\Controller\BlockController::content'
    _title: 'Block Header'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### block_header.libraries.yml

```
block_header:
version: 1.x
css:
    theme:
        css/block_header.css: {}
```

#### BlockController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\block_header\Controller\BlockController.
 */
namespace Drupal\block_header\Controller;
class BlockController {
  public function content() {
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('Sample Text!'),
    );
  }
}
```

#### block_header.module

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 */
function block_header_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'block_header') {
    $variables['page']['#attached']['library'][] = 'block_header/block_header';
  }
}
```

#### BlockHeader.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\block_header\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'Header' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "block_header",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Block Header"),
 *   category = @Translation("Block Header"),
 * )
 */

class BlockHeader extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    if (!empty($config['block_header_title']) && ($config['block_header_text'])) {
      $title = $config['block_header_title'];
      $descp = $config['block_header_text'];
    }
    else {
      $title = $this->t('<div>Atención! Titulo no configurado!</div> </p>');
      $descp = $this->t('<div>Atención! Descripción no configurada!</div>');
    }
    $block = array
        (
            'title' => array
            (
             '#prefix' => '<div class="title"><p>', /* HERE I ADD THE CSS TAGS */
             '#suffix' => '</p></div>',
             '#markup' => t('@title', array('@title' => $title,)),
            ),
            'description' => array
            (
             '#prefix' => '<div class="descp"><p>', /* HERE I ADD THE CSS TAGS */
             '#suffix' => '</p></div>',
             '#markup' => t('@descp', array('@descp' => $descp,))
            ),
        );
    return $block;  

  }


   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $form['block_header_title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Titulo del Bloque'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Titulo del Bloque'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['block_header_title']) ? $config['block_header_title'] : '',
    );

    $form['block_header_text'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Descripción'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Descripción del bloque'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['block_header_text']) ? $config['block_header_text'] : '',
    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::blockSubmit($form, $form_state);
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $this->configuration['block_header_title'] = $values['block_header_title'];
    $this->configuration['block_header_text'] = $values['block_header_text'];
    $this->configuration['block_header_title'] = $form_state->getValue('block_header_title');
    $this->configuration['block_header_text'] = $form_state->getValue('block_header_text');
  }
}
```

This is the structure of the directory containing the module.

> [image: My module structure]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks go inside the .module file.

**block_header.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 */
function block_header_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'block_header') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'block_header/block_header';
  }
}
```

Just FYI, this did not work:

```
    $variables['elements']['#attached']['library'][] = 'block_header/block_header';
```

**block_header.libraries.yml**

```
block_header:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/block_header.css: {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! this *.module file worked!!! Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Hawk I think Clive's answer is better for your own custom block case.

Comment: I disagree with your prior comment, may I? And if yes: why not?

Comment: `I disagree with your prior comment, may I?` yes, you may.

Comment: I agree with No Sssweat, Clive's answer is more appropriate.  preprocess_block is heavy handed for just attaching a stylesheet to a particular block.  It's going to run for every block in the module.

Answer (score 4):

The attachment should be on the block itself:

```
$block = [
        '#attached'=> ['library' => ['block_header/block_header']],
        'title' => array
        (
         '#prefix' => '<div class="title"><p>', /* HERE I ADD THE CSS TAGS */
         '#suffix' => '</p></div>',
         '#markup' => t('@title', array('@title' => $title,)),
        ),
        'description' => array
        (
         '#prefix' => '<div class="descp"><p>', /* HERE I ADD THE CSS TAGS */
         '#suffix' => '</p></div>',
         '#markup' => t('@descp', array('@descp' => $descp,))
        ),
    ];
```

And remember YAML is sensitive to white space, make sure your libraries file is formatted correctly:

```
block_header:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/block_header.css: {}
```